# visual Studio .net 2013 won't load Oracle.Dataacess dll

Tags: visual-studio-2013, oracle11g

I have a VB.net 2005 application I am trying to upgrade to VB.net 2013, everything else has worked but when I try to add a reference to the DLL for Oracle.dataacess it doesn't seem to work.

I don't get any visible errors, I check the box to select the reference, I hit OK and then the window closes.

My calls to items within that dll still show up in error, when I open my references again I see the DLL is not selected.

The DLL is a 32 bit DLL, the VS Studio looks to be running 32 bit, I ran it as admin.

If I open VS 2008 and reference the DLL it works fine.

so Not sure what is going on.

Edit: the DLL is shown on the references as Oracle.DataAccess Version 2.112.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, for some reason it had the old References locked in, I had to go into the solution explorer and under references to delete the old one, then go back in and fully add the new one.

This worked.